# JQuery Killing Function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery, so I'm a little confused here. I have a button that, onclick, runs this function. When the JQuery is commented out, the alert goes off when the button is clicked. But with the JQuery, nothing is alerted when the button is clicked. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadList(type){
    alert(type);
    if(type == "private"){
        //$.post("fileone.php", { page: "private" };
    }else{
        //$.post("fileone.php", { page: "public" } );
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a syntax error on line 5, you're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: I'd suggest OP testing his code with his javascript console open as well, F12 in Chrome/IE and Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox would show the syntax error instantly.

Comment: It seems that jQuery isn't killing the function, but the function is killing itself.

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error. The first line with jQuery needs a closing parenthesis. Check your error console in your browser and it will tell you about this sort of error.

Comment: I tried, I couldn't find it in firebug. Thanks. It gets hard to see syntax errors when you've been programming all day

Comment: Did you try adding the closing parenthesis to your first `$.post()` as Phil suggested and it still doesn't run?

Comment: Hey @FabricioMatte, Yeah it runs perfectly. I just didn't set an answer earlier because Stack Overflow restricts you from setting one for about 20 minutes after asking the question. And These guys answered in about 10 seconds haha